# Hibernate, c3p0, PostgreSQL : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, c3p0, pgadmin

When I use Hibernate pool, all works perfectly. However, when I'm trying to change the pool to c3p0, I don't get any errors from the client's side (initializing c3p0 without errors) but I get "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" with every connection c3p0 tries to make (in this case, 5).

**I see this message in the pgadmin III logs in "Server Status"**

I've done my research, nothing works.
What I've done:

- changed configs, no result
- inbound/outbound port 5432 firewall enabled

Configs - postgres

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
```

Config - pg_hba

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host     all     all     0.0.0.0/0   md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host     all     all     127.0.0.1/24    md5
```

Hibernate cfg:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/{db_name}</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</property>
```

**The important thing is: it does work somehow (single connections when needed are made) but it seems that c3p0 can't make the pool server side**

Comment: That error specifically occurs when you get a TCP/IP `RST` response to a connection. So it's not an auth / HBA issue, it's lower level. Wrong port number, wrong hostname, etc.

Comment: do you see the message "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" in an Exception? If so, please list it. In a log file? which? is the DBMS local to your application (ie is your jdbc URL of the form `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname` or `jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/dbname`?)

Comment: I see the message about no connection only in the Server Status logs in pgadmin. But how can it be lower level if it does work the other way? I added jdbc URL to listings. Thanks!